# Magento 2 Show only a total number of active products in category in admin

Tags: magento2, admin, category

I have a lot of products on my webshop, and so many of them are inactive, but will come back later.

I wonder if it's possible to show only numbers of active products besides each category? maybe a custom module is needed for this? If so, what do I need to do?

[image]

It's OK to still show all products inclusive the inactive ones on the right side after clicking on the categories. It's only the overview on the left site I need to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override Catalog Block File : vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Category/Tree.php

**Add**

```
protected $_productCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
    ...
}
```

**Replace**

```
public function buildNodeName($node)
{
    $result = $this->escapeHtml($node->getName());
    if ($this->_withProductCount) {
        $result .= ' (' . $node->getProductCount() . ')';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

With

```
public function buildNodeName($node)
{
    $result = $this->escapeHtml($node->getName());
    if ($this->_withProductCount) {
        $result .= ' (' . $this->getEnabledProducts($node->getId()) . ')';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Add New Function**

```
public function getEnabledProducts($id)
{
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($id);
    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    return $collection->count();
}
```

Now you are get only enabled products count.

Comment: better filter for visibily like
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 'in', [\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH, \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG] )

Answer (score 0):

**Add New Function**

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status;

public function isCategoryHasProducts($category)
    {
        $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        $collection->setVisibility(array(Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH, Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG));
        $collection->addFieldToFilter('status', Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
        return $collection->getSize();
    }
```